# Brezis' exercise 8.7: prove that $\bar{u} \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.7** Let $I=(0,1)$. Given a function $u$ defined on $I$, set
> $$
> \bar{u}(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> u(x) & \text { if } x \in I, \\
> 0 & \text { if } x \in \mathbb{R}, x \notin I.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> 1. Assume that $u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Prove that $\bar{u} \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$.
> 2. Conversely, let $u \in L^p(I)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$ be such that $\bar{u} \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)$.
> 3. Let $u \in L^p(I)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Show that $u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)$ IFF there exists a constant $C$ such that
>    $$
>    \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} \bar{u} \varphi^{\prime}\right| \leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R})} \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}),
>    $$
>    where $p^*$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We need auxiliary results (in the same book), i.e.,

> - **Theorem 8.12** Let $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)$ IFF $u=0$ on $\partial I$.
> - **Proposition 8.3** Let $u \in L^p (I)$ with $p \in (1, \infty]$. Then $u \in W^{1, p} (I)$ IFF there is a constant $C>0$ such that
>   $$
>   \left|\int_I u \varphi' \right| \leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^{p^*}(I)}
>   \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(I) .
>   $$

1. Let $v := \overline{u'}$, i.e., $v$ is the extension of $u'$ on $\mathbb R$. Clearly, $v \in L^p (\mathbb R)$. There is a sequence $(u_n) \subset C_c^1 (I)$ such that $|u_n -u|_{W^{1, p}(I)} \to 0$. For $\varphi \in C_c^1 (\mathbb R)$, we have
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \int_{\mathbb R} \bar{u}  \varphi' = \int_I u  \varphi' = \lim_n \int_I u_n  \varphi' = \lim_n \int_I u_n'  \varphi = \lim_n \int_I u'  \varphi = \lim_n \int_{\mathbb R} v  \varphi.
   \end{align*}
   $$
   It follows that $\bar u \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\bar u' =v$.
2. It follows from $\bar{u} \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ that $u \in W^{1, p} (I)$. By **Theorem 8.12**, it remains to prove that $u = 0$ on $\partial I$. We have
   $$
   u(0) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} u(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \bar u(x) = \lim_{x \uparrow 0} \bar u(x) =0.
   $$
   Similarly, we get $u(1)=0$.
3. 

- $\implies$  This follows from $(1)$ and **Proposition 8.3**.
- $\impliedby$ This follows from **Proposition 8.3** and $(2)$.